Bash script to rename files according to a list in a file: How do I handle spaces?
I have to rename a large number of files according to an Excel list (yeah, I know).
So my approach was to export the filenames from the Excel into  filenames.csv with this format:
this_is_a_file.ext ; new_filename_1.ext
this_is_another_file.ext ; new_filename_2.ext
this is a filename with spaces.ext ; new_filename_3.ext

For the renaming, I want to use something like this bash script:
lstrn() {
 while IFS= read -r line; do
    oldfilename=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
    newfilename=`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`
    mv $oldfilename $newfilename
 done < $1
}

Which I would run with:
$ lstrn filenames.csv

This works fine as long as neither the old nor the new filenames have any spaces in them.
As I understand, the $1 is the text block with the old filename, the $2 would be the ; and the $3 is the new filename in each line of my filenames.csv.
I think I get why this wouldn't work with spaces in the filenames... I need to to replace the awk '{print $1}' part, right?
I'm just completely lost on how to get this to work with spaces and would really appreciate if somebody had an idea how to do this!

while IFS=; read old new ; do mv "$old" "$new" ; done should work. BTW, the sample you have given is not CSV, because it uses semicolons, fields with spaces are not quoted, etc.

Do you really have all those extra spaces around the file names? You have this_is_a_file.ext ; new_filename_1.ext in your file and not this_is_a_file.ext;new_filename_1.ext? Can we be sure there is only ever one ; per line, and none of your file names contain ;?

@FedKad You need to quote the ; in IFS=; lest it be taken as a command separator by the shell. Also note that the OP has spaces around the file names, so those need to be handled too. This kind of thing is why we really don't want answers being posted as comments.

Sorry for the confusion! My list started as a comma-separated CSV with quotes over fields with spaces, etc. But the quotation marks kept showing up in the file names after renaming, so I removed them. Then I had file names with commas and I replaces the separating commas with semicolons... until my list was a somewhat of a mess that used to be a CSV.  But @terdon's solution worked like a charm - see below. Thanks for your suggestions anyway!

If we can assume that your file names do not contain ; (this is a huge assumption, ; is perfectly valid in file names, so you need to be sure about this), then you can just read your input text file, split on ; and save the result in two variables, allowing you to rename:
while IFS=';' read old new ; do mv "$old" "$new" ; done < filenames.csv

Here, we set the input field separator (IFS) to a ;, then read the input file, split on ; and assign the old and new filenames to their respective variables.
Now, your input example also has spaces around the ;. This means that the file name isn't "this_is_a_file.ext" but "this_is_a_file.ext " with an extra space, and that file won't exist. So before running the command above, you need to remove those extra spaces. You can do this with sed, telling it to replace all cases of two or more spaces (  *, that is one space, then another space and a *) around a ; with just the ;:
$ sed 's/  *;  */;/g' filenames.csv 
this_is_a_file.ext;new_filename_1.ext
this_is_another_file.ext;new_filename_2.ext
this is a filename with spaces.ext;new_filename_3.ext

Combining the two commands gives the one you really want to run:
$ sed 's/  *;  */;/g' filenames.csv |  
   while IFS=';' read old new ; do 
     echo "mv \"$old\" \"$new\"" ; 
done 
mv "this_is_a_file.ext" "new_filename_1.ext"
mv "this_is_another_file.ext" "new_filename_2.ext"
mv "this is a filename with spaces.ext" "new_filename_3.ext"

Once you are sure that is the right output, remove the echo and run again to actually rename the files:
sed 's/  *;  */;/g' filenames.csv |  
   while IFS=';' read old new ; do 
     mv -- "$old" "$new" ; 
done 

The -- is there to protect against file names starting with -. See What does "--" mean in terminal commands?.

THANK YOU SO MUCH! You saved me a lot of time!
My bad about the whole semicolon thing... and actually some file names had them. So first I fixed my list with the file names. I put everything in a textfile and used "§" as IFS.
After that, this command worked like a charm:
while IFS='§' read old new ; do mv -- "$old" "$new" ; done < filenames.txt
